# How do I apply the findings of a Pandas GroupBy to the source data

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, python-dedupe

I'm doing a name de-dupe using pandas de_dupe and have multiple steps.

Firstly I train and de-dupe the source data.

```
deDupedNames = dedupe_dataframe( sourceData, columnsOfInterest, config_name=configName)
```

Next I discard data sets where the cluster has only 1 participant

```
dedupedComplexSets = dedupe_df_sorted.groupby( ['cluster id']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Next I need to examine each group of matches (grouped by 'cluster id') and confirm that at least the first 3 characters of the names in each group are the same.
I'm doing this by iterating through each group in the dedupedComplexSets and further grouping the content of each group by the first three characters of each *Surname*.

```
for name, group in dedupedComplexSetsGrouped:
    bySurnamePrefix = group.groupby(group.Surname.str[:3]).size()
```

Finally I'd like to flag each row that belongs to a de-duped cluster where the number of Surname 'begins withs' is > 1

```
for name, group in dedupedComplexSetsGrouped:
    bySurnamePrefix = group.groupby(group.Surname.str[:3]).size()

    if( len( bySurnamePrefix) > 1):
        dedupedComplexSets[group, 'RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch'] = True
```

However, I can't write back to the original dataframe due to the 'mutable hash' error or other errors.

How is a problem like this solved?  And how is the output from examination of groups communicated outside of the Grouped Set dataframe?  There must be a correct way...?

Example data in (where RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch is a scripted column):

RowID|FirstName|Surname

```
12345, fred, surname, false, 
24385, frred, surname, false,
```

Example data out:
RowID|FirstName|Surname|cluster id|confidence|RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch

```
12345, fred, surname, false, 1, .9999995, True
24385, frred, surname, false, 1, .999992, True
```

Note that I'm using the RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch as a way of recording the mismatch.  Perhaps there is a more effective way to do this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? Maybe need to change `dedupedComplexSets[group, 'RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch'] = True` to `dedupedComplexSets.loc[group.index, 'RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch'] = True`

Comment: but then get `True`s and `NaN`s in `RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch` column

Comment: @Jezrail - I'll try that in the morning.
NaN's are ok - I can remove these rows / keep these rows.

Comment: @Jozerail - Works like magic.
For anyone wondering what the next step was, saving the original DataFrame to disk saved the changes made to the Grouped RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch column to be persisted to disk.  IE the original DataFrame reflected the changes performed in the Grouping exercise.  Thanks Jezrail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Jezrael as seen in comments above:

Replace:
`dedupedComplexSets[group, 'RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch'] = True to`

with

```
dedupedComplexSets.loc[group.index, 'RowClusterHasLeadingCharacterMismatch'] = True
```

My commentary: the changes made to dedupedComplexSets will be reflected in *dedupedComplexSets* and can be persisted to CSV.